# Postgres FATAL: could not open log file permission denied

Tags: postgresql, docker, logging, permissions

I am deploying postgres in docker and trying to output some logs, however, I am getting an error saying permission denied for the logs file.  If I disable logging, everything works.  The permission thing only happens when I enable log collection.

Here is a snippet of my docker-compose:

```
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:14.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${BP_ADMIN_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${BP_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./admin/${BP_ENV:-dev}/database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./admin/${BP_ENV:-dev}/config:/mnt/admin
      - ./data/log_db:/mnt/log
      - ./data/hist_data:/mnt/data
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=on -c log_rotation_age=1d -c log_directory=/mnt/log -c log_destination='stderr' -c log_filename='postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

The error is as follows:

```
UTC [1] FATAL:  could not open log file "/mnt/log/postgresql-2022-01-10_224118.log": Permission denied
```

I am running this on a Linux Ubuntu 20-04 VM.  I saw some answers where they changed the permissions of the host directory.  That is something I did not want to do.  I also saw some old 2016 answers of work arounds.  But I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution available now.

Note:  I did not get this error until this morning.  For whatever reason, it was working last week.

Comment: There's a section "Arbitrary `--user` Notes" at the end of the [Docker Hub `postgres` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres); does a setup like that help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres runs under a user called 'postgres' with UID 999 inside the container. When that user accesses files you have bind mounted from the host, the container UID needs to have access to those files on the host.

You get an error because UID 999 doesn't have access to `./data/log_db/postgresql-2022-01-10_224118.log` on your host machine.

To allow the docker user to create files in the directory, you can change the group owner of the directory to group 999 (which is the group id of the postgres user in the container). Set the directory to be fully accessible by owner and group members. Then set the setgid bit on the directory so all files in the directory will inherit the group ownership.

```
chown :999 ./data/log_db
chmod 770 ./data/log_db
chmod g+s ./data/log_db
```

Now you should be able to run your container. You'll see that the log files created are owned by user '999' and are only accessible by that user (and root).

Comment: what would be the best-practice way to overcome this error?

Comment: @RuiNian I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Hans!  When I go to deploy my application, would I need to run this on the docker host of every deployment?  It is weird because I cloned the repo on my Mac and it did not need this for whatever reason.  How does Mac and Linux behaviours differ?

Comment: Yes, you need to give the container permission to write to the host file system when you use a bind mount like this. If you store the logs in a docker volume instead, you might not need to give access. I'd think it'd be the same on macs, since the file systems are very much alike, afaik. But I've never worked on a mac, so I don't know.